# "Intelligent" word wrapping on Visual Studio Code

Tags: word-wrap, visual-studio-code

I was quite annoyed of having to scroll horizontaly on VScode, so I set the following settings to enable word-wrapping:

```
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.wrappingIndent": "indent"
```

However, I find it quite anoying that it wraps in places where I wouldn't want, for example, for a function call like this one:

```
myLongNameFunc(longNameVarA, longNameVarB);
```

It is wrapping it like this, splitting it on the semicolon:

```
myLongNameFunc(longNameVarA, longNameVarB)
    ;
```

And I would rather see something like this:

```
myLongNameFunc(longNameVarA, 
    longNameVarB);
```

Is it possible to set this configuration in some way? Allowing it to wrap on spaces if possible, for instance?

Thanks,

Comment: You could possibly remove the semicolon from this setting:    // Characters that will be used as word separators when doing word related navigations or operations
  "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",    That will have other navigation effects though.  And you have to experiment to see if it fixes your issue of breaking on the semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for the try but it didn't work. I overrode my settings with this:

"editor.wordSeparators": " _%/*-=+,."

And I am still getting my function call split just before the semicolon. Any other guess?

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time... but I see v1.42 will have a new wrapping strategy option which fixes your example for me:

> Editor: Wrapping Strategy

choose `advanced`

> Controls the algorithm that computes wrapping points.
>
> - `simple`: Assumes that all characters are of the same width. This is a fast algorithm that works correctly for monospace fonts and
>     certain scripts (like Latin characters) where glyphs are of equal
>     width.
> - `advanced`: Delegates wrapping points computation to the browser. This is a slow algorithm, that might cause freezes for large files,
>     but it works correctly in all cases.

As the setting warns, `advanced` could adversely affect large files but it does properly wrap your example.